# How can i set color to floating menu block

Tags: magento-1.9

How can i set color for floating menu block. when i scroll down its not highlighted menu block.

[image]

Comment: Hi Jeeva, it's hard to answer that form a screenshot. can you post a link?

Comment: am just developing through localhost.

Answer (score 3):

There is a great post on stackoverflow that might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19430812/387136

They use jQuery to set a class on scrolling. you could use that to set a highlight behind the menu

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(document).scrollTop() > 100) {
            $(".header-nav").addClass("scrolled");
        } else {
            $(".header-nav").removeClass("scrolled");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks for your answer,  could you  help  me this question

Answer (score 0):

@Jeeva Rathinam Can you offer more information? Generally if you're trying to change the color of a block, you're modifying the color associated with some element(s) within the template assigned to said block....so you can either use inline css...or use regular css id/classes and store your css declarations in an external css file..just make sure you're including that css file within scope of the page.